# Enemy loads, but doesn't move

Tags: javascript, game-physics

**Thanks for the help, code below now is functional.**

Previous problem (**resolved**):

*I'm creating a game, and the **enemy loads, but doesn't move**.  The player moves, so I've been searching for the error specific to the enemy's movement, but I haven't been able to determine the fault.*

Enemy gets called to move by this function.

```
function moveAll() {
    redShip.move(); // moves player, working
    enemy.move(); // moves enemy, works now after correction.
}
```

The Enemy's move function

```
const UFO_SPEED = 1.9;
const UFO_TIME_BETWEEN_CHANGE_DIR = 85;

UFOClass.prototype = new movingWrapPositionClass();

function UFOClass() {
    this.x = Math.random()*600;
    this.y = Math.random()*800;
    this.xv = 0;
    this.yv = 0;
    this.cyclesTilDirectionChange = 0; // added line to make work


    this.superclassMove = this.move;
    this.move = function() {
        this.superclassMove();

    this.cyclesTilDirectionChange--;
    if(this.cyclesTilDirectionChange <= 0) {
        var randAng = Math.random() * Math.PI*2.0;
        this.xv = Math.cos(randAng) * UFO_SPEED;
        this.yv = Math.sin(randAng) * UFO_SPEED;
        this.cyclesTilDirectionChange = UFO_TIME_BETWEEN_CHANGE_DIR;
        }
    }
```

Shared movement function between player and enemy

```
function movingWrapPositionClass() {
     this.move = function() {
     this.x += this.xv;
     this.y += this.yv;
     this.handleScreenWrap();
}
```

Adding the Ship's function which is working

```
const SPACESPEED_DECAY_MULT = 0.99;
const THRUST_POWER = 0.15;
const TURN_RATE = 0.06;

shipClass.prototype = new movingWrapPositionClass();

function shipClass() {
    this.myShot = new shotClass();
    this.x = 400;
    this.y = 300;
    this.ang = -3;
    this.xv = 0;
    this.yv = 0;
    this.myShipPic; // which picture to use


    this.keyHeld_Gas = false;
    this.keyHeld_TurnLeft = false;
    this.keyHeld_TurnRight = false;

    this.controlKeyUp;
    this.controlKeyRight;
    this.controlKeyDown;
    this.controlKeyLeft;
    this.controlKeyForShotFire;


    this.setupInput = function(upKey, rightKey, downKey, leftKey, shotKey) {
        this.controlKeyUp = upKey;
        this.controlKeyRight = rightKey;
        this.controlKeyDown = downKey;
        this.controlKeyLeft = leftKey;  
        this.controlKeyForShotFire = shotKey;

    }

this.superclassMove = this.move;
this.move = function() {
    this.x += Math.cos(this.ang) * this.xv;
    this.y += Math.sin(this.ang) * this.yv;

    this.superclassMove();
    this.xv *= SPACESPEED_DECAY_MULT;
    this.yv *= SPACESPEED_DECAY_MULT;

    if(this.keyHeld_Gas) {
        this.xv += THRUST_POWER;
        this.yv += THRUST_POWER;
        this.superclassMove();

    }
    if(this.keyHeld_TurnLeft) {
        this.ang -= TURN_RATE;
        }  
    if(this.keyHeld_TurnRight) {
        this.ang += TURN_RATE;  
        }
```

Comment: Can you create a working code snippet, so we can see it in action?

Comment: myfunkyside, thank you for the quick response.  I've added the player's movement (ship) to show a working code snippet.

Comment: `if(this.keyHeld_Gas) {`: looks like you do not use event handlers???

Comment: By working *Code Snippet*, I meant this: **[link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356678), [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753), [link](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)**. What you currently have are *Code Blocks/Samples*. When I said "see it in action", I meant that literally :)

Comment: Cool, I've never used that before.  I'll put my code in there shortly.

Comment: The idea is still to keep your code [as short/compact as possible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), just enough to let us see the problem, without clouding the important code with unnecessary code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  While I was trying to mess around with Code Snippet, I found the error.  I didn't create a var for cyclesTilDirectionChange.  Once I did that, everyone worked out.  I'm also trying to get better at asking questions on here.  I'm trying to figure out what's the right amount of code to post.